# Trying to change flash rate of camera with onClick

Tags: android, onclick, android-camera

I want when I press the button btlento the camera flash blink slowly for that I made these variables:

```
int counter = 1;
int deloy = 2000;
int poriod = 2000;
int deloy1 = 1000;
int poriod1 = 2000;
```

and this is the button with the code:

```
case R.id.btlento:

        do{
            cameraOn();
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    cameraOff();
                    counter = counter+1;
                }
            },deloy1,poriod1);

            Timer timer2 = new Timer();
            timer2.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    cameraOn();
                }
            },deloy,poriod);

                }while(counter>=60);
        break;
```

And the other button have to blink faster, so I made these other variables:

```
int j = 1;
int delay = 600;
int period = 600;
int delay1 = 300;
int period1 = 600;
```

And these is the button with the method:

```
case R.id.btrapid:

        do{
            cameraOn();
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    cameraOff();
                    j = j+1;
                }
            },delay1,period1);

            Timer timer2 = new Timer();
            timer2.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    cameraOn();
                }
            },delay,period);

                }while(j>=5);

        break;
```

Now they are blinking nut they never stop, why????
The method cameraOn is:

```
private void cameraOn() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             camera = Camera.open();
             parameters = camera.getParameters();
             parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
             camera.setParameters(parameters);
        }
```

And cameraOff is:

```
private void cameraOff() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
             camera.setParameters(parameters);
             camera.release();
             camera = null;
        }
```

Comment: Are your `cameraOn()` and `cameraOff` methods being called? Can you post the source for those methods as well?

Comment: I edited the question for add both methods, Sorry!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `counter` and `j` are not modified somewhere else, you never enter the while blocks, it should probably be:

```
while(counter<=60)
```

and:

```
while(j<60)
```

Comment: I edited again the question, because I changed for do-while. Thanks